# Test messages onto a JMS queue

Tags: jms

Can anyone recommend a tool for quickly posting test messages onto a JMS queue? The tool should allow the user to enter some data, perhaps an XML payload, and then submit it to a queue? I know I could probably knock something up reasonably quickly to do this but I thought I'd ask first before reinventing the wheel. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

In ActiveMQ there is a very nice web admin console that allows you to send custom messages to any queue, you can even send several messages at once to stress test your application.

If you need something more generic, SoapUI has a [JMS module](http://www.soapui.org/JMS/getting-started.html). I never tried it, but the overall quality of this application suite is very promising.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [IBM WebSphere Developer Technical Journal: Running a standalone Java application on WebSphere MQ V6.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0610_woolf/0610_woolf.html).  Although the article is geared toward WebSphere MQ, the code download is plain-vanilla JMS with JNDI lookups and should run on any compliant JMS provider.

The nice thing about this is that it works for both queues and topics and will either be a message producer or a message consumer based on the run-time options.  You can fire one up as a producer and another (or two or three or four) as a consumer to test out a queue or topic.  The code is very simple non-gui which makes it an excellent starting point for experimentation.  You could for example, easily modify it to set message expiry or bridge between topics and queues.

Answer (score 1):

Two sourceforge Projects might be interesting:

- [Apache ActiveMQBrowser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/activemqbrowser/)
- [QBrowser for GlassFish JMS / WebLogic MQ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qbrowserv2/)

They are from the same developer and quite active

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [HermesJMS](http://www.hermesjms.com/).  It is very feature rich, some concepts are a bit hard to understand...

Answer (score 0):

I have written a client for Activemq and Hornetq that does just that. It's a commercial but there's a 60-day trial period. You can find it at:

[Rockeye JMS](http://www.rockeyesoftware.com/download.php)

Regards,
Serge